# Approximate inverse Laplace transform in terms of the moments of a function

Tags: probability-distributions, laplace-transform

If $F(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(t)$ and
\begin{equation}
F(s)=\frac{1}{1-aG(s)}
\end{equation}
where $G(s)$ is the Laplace transform of a known probability density distribution $g(t)$ whose moments are $\langle t^n\rangle$.

Is it possible to approximate $f(t)$ in terms of the first moments  $\langle t^n\rangle$? At least in the limit of large $t\gg1$?

Comment: this may help : https://www.jstor.org/stable/2039641

Answer (score 0):

The large-$t$ behavior of $f(t)$ will be dominated by the small-$s$ behavior of $F(s)$, so it makes sense to include only the first few moments of $g(t)$. If I take a normal distribution for $g$, I obtain
$$f(t)=-\frac{\sqrt{2} \sinh (t\sqrt{2/a-2 } )}{\sqrt{a(1-a)}}.$$
So the large-$t$ behavior is either exponential or oscillatory, depending on whether $a$ is larger or smaller than 1.

<sub>More generally, for $\langle t\rangle=\mu$, $\langle t^2\rangle=\mu^2+\sigma^2$, one has
$$f(t)=-2 e^{\frac{{\mu} t}{{\mu}^2+{\sigma}^2}} \sinh \left(\frac{t \sqrt{(2-a) a {\mu}^2+2 (1-a) a {\sigma}^2}}{a \left({\mu}^2+{\sigma}^2\right)}\right)\biggl((2-a) a {\mu}^2+2 (1-a) a {\sigma}^2\biggr)^{-1/2}.$$</sub>